# How return simle text in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I have a simple code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract testApp {
    function abc() public pure returns(string memory) {
        string memory text = "test";
        return text;
    }
}
```

When i try return text value i see error
`call to testApp.abc errored: Error occurred: invalid opcode.`
And more info like

*The execution might have thrown OR the EVM version used by the selected environment is not compatible with the compiler EVM version.*

How can i return pure text/string?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. This error usually occurs for one of the following reasons.

1. You are trying to access the function from non deployed contract address.
2. You are trying to access the function from an invalid contract address.
3. The compiler version is wrong or invalid.

Returning pure text/string is possible and accessible between contracts and outside contracts. Please refer below example. Hope this helps.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract TextContract {
    function getText() public pure returns (string memory) {
         // Custom logic you can write here
         string memory data = "Custom Data";
         return data;
    }
}
```